# Scrapy-splash can't load site

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I want to crawl a site(http://www.adl.com.tr/en/c/cengiz-abazoglu-koleksiyonu-4) by scrapy-splash. But couldn't load items who made with javascript. I tried increase splash.wait(0.5) to (10) and enable DOWNLOAD_DELAY=5. Nothing changed.

What do you recommend?

[image: Screenshot rendered site by Splash]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website works for me in Splash 3.0, but not in Splash 2.3.2. 
In Splash 3.0 WebKit was updated to a much more recent version, likely this fixed the incompatibility.

Comment: Splash updated to 3.0 after a day of asking my questions :) But I did not follow new updates. Thank you for your time.